# Amazon S3 get S3 Object by URL in Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am looking to rename (or move) my S3 objects, I have their URLs like https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/sample-bucket/temp/sample-picture.jpg

Is there any standard way in Ruby SDK to get Aws::S3::Object by only URL or I have to parse it by regular expression for example ?

In Java SDK there is [AmazonS3URI.java](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/806e98ecd35ba00d9dc0da35ab962c7caa76293c/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3URI.java)

Comment: What version of [aws-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) you are using?

Comment: I am using gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any method to just take the s3 url and get the object. I ended up with parsing it by myself.

Answer (score -1):

No, the AWS SDK for Ruby v2-3 doesn't support this.

However, here's a quick snippet of code that would do the trick (it's based loosely off the Java code you referenced):

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

# @param uri [String] your fully-qualified URL
# @return head_object [Aws::S3::Types::HeadObjectOutput] metadata on object
def from_uri(uri)

    # Parse the S3 URL into its bucket and object key components
    uri = URI.parse(s3_url)
    bucket_name = uri.host.split('.')[0]
    object_key = uri.path[1..-1] # Remove leading slash

    client = Aws::S3::Client.new

    client.head_object({
        bucket: bucket_name, 
        key: object_key, 
    })

data = from_uri("https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/sample-bucket/temp/sample-picture.jpg")
puts data.to_h
```

You'll want to convert this method into a class and extract the client instantiation into the class init, but this answers your question.

Also note: The HEAD action retrieves metadata from an object without returning the object itself.